# How can i use select to string in linq?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, linq

How cani use below codes string id = ( from in .....) how?

```
using (StockProcedureDataContext stock = new StockProcedureDataContext())
            {


                id = (from m in stock.StockTools
                      from ss in stock.RefStockStatus
                      where (m.statusid == 3 || m.statusid == 5) &&
                      ss.id == m.statusid && m.id == ItemID
                      select m.id);
```

#### How  can i do above wthout using below?

```
id = (from m in stock.StockTools
                      from ss in stock.RefStockStatus
                      where (m.statusid == 3 || m.statusid == 5) &&
                      ss.id == m.statusid && m.id == ItemID
                      select m).ToList()[0].id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to retrieve a single result user [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) or [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx).

If you use `First()` and the result is null.It will throws exception but not in `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
var query = (from m in stock.StockTools
                      from ss in stock.RefStockStatus
                      where (m.statusid == 3 || m.statusid == 5) &&
                      ss.id == m.statusid && m.id == ItemID
                      select m.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
query.Single()
```

That's it.

Comment: Be careful about using Single, it throws exception if items.Count!=1. From MSDN : "Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence."

Answer (score 4):

```
id = (from m in stock.StockTools
                      from ss in stock.RefStockStatus
                      where (m.statusid == 3 || m.statusid == 5) &&
                      ss.id == m.statusid && m.id == ItemID
                      select m.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety...

```
query.Take(1)
```

Comment: But that returns an enumerable.